# Add section to one single citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

I am wondering whether it is possible to add a Section reference to one single entry of a citation. To be clear, let me introduce a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    
    \cite[Section 2]{A} \cite[Section 2]{A,B}    
    
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

with its bib file `biblio.bib`

```
@article{A,
    author = {G Gare},
    title = {Citation style},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2019}
    }
    
@article{B,
    author = {G Gare},
    title = {Citation style 2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year = {2019}
}
```

The output of this is [image]

Would it be possible to have something like `[1,Section 2, 2]`? Or, conversely, would you think it is cleaner to write `\cite[Section 2]{A}, \cite{B}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find output of the type `[1,Section 2, 2]` to be potentially confusing: Is "Section 2" a (slightly odd-looking...) citation call-out in its own right, or is it an affix to `1`?

I think it's better to output `[1, Section 2; 2]` -- note the use of a semicolon. Even clearer, though, has got to be `[1, Section 2] and [2]`.

The following solution uses the `\citetext` and `\citealp` macros of the `natbib` package, as well as the `plainnat` bibliography style, which is `natbib`'s re-implementation of the `plain` bibliography style.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{A,
    author  = {G. Gare},
    title   = {Citation style 1},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = {2019},
}
@article{B,
    author  = {G. Gare},
    title   = {Citation style 2},
    journal = {Journal},
    year    = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\citetext{\citealp[Section 2]{A};\citealp{B}}   

\cite[Section 2]{A} and \cite{B}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go for the plain `\cite[Section 2]{A} and \cite{B}`. Looks better and crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

With the Biblatex package instead of BibTeX there are commands like `cites` for having different prenotes/postnotes for different entries:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

% \renewcommand\multicitedelim{; }
\begin{document}
\cite[Section 2]{A} \cites[Section 2]{A}{B}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

With multicite commands like these you can have any number of citations with their own individual postnotes (and/or prenotes), with things like `\cite[13]{A}[17]{B}[167-176]{C}`. The line that is commented out would yield "`[1, Section 2; 2]`" instead.

Comment: Thanks! I guess therefore there is no option of this kind with BibTex?

Comment: I don't know, but it wouldn't surprise me if there is some addon package for BibTeX to do multicites like that. So much has been done with BibTeX, especially before Biblatex arrived.